# C decryption program

Tags: c, encryption, while-loop

When I compile the program and run it, it does not print anything. I believe the problem is on the while but I can't understand what is wrong. It is supposed to convert hex to ASCII and then the encrypted message.

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
         int p;
//Opening a file
         FILE*tp; 
             tp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if(tp == NULL)
         {
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            return 0;
         }
         else
         {
//Decryption code
            while((p=fscanf(" %x",&p))!=EOF)
            { 
            p=p >> 2;
            p=p - 200;
            printf(" %c",p);
            }
         }
        return 1;
        fclose(tp);
    }
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings ! The parameters you are passing to fscanf are incorrect. If you had compiler warnings enabled you would have been helpfully informed of this and saved yourself a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf()` returns number of input items successfully matched and assigned, not input items themselves. Also, as mentioned above, you need to pass file pointer to the function. Try this: `while(fscanf(tp, "%x", &p) != EOF)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to specify and provide the FILE pointer "tp" to the fscanf function.